# Amano shrimp disappearing 1 day after adding to an aquarium

Tags: aquarium, fish, shrimp

As a test (as I was cautious even after the shop keeper said it's fine), I bought 3 Amano shrimp to add to my aquarium. One day later only one was still there (right top of the pic). All three were too large to get into the filter (except through the output), so I guess they were eaten.

Aside from the fish in the photo, there are two antenna catfish and two loaches (the variety that is only on the ground and their mouths are too small to even eat the fire tetra).

As I watched the single survivor today I found him hiding only in the almost out of water corner of the filter system. So I guess he must be deathly afraid.

Now what I'm asking is, is there anything wrong with shrimp of that size and this aquarium? Or do I need more shrimp-specific hiding places, or is there a deathly threat to them that I don't recognize as such? (Currently I'm out of ideas as to why the other two died and that one seems afraid, and the shop keeper wasn't a real help there either.)

[image]

Comment: Do you do water tests regularly? What is the reading of the last one? What kind of fish are in there?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid comment, but are you sure they aren't just hiding? If shrimp are "deathly afraid" they usually curl up to protect their soft bellies with the shell of their tails.

Comment: @Elmy At least I tried to look everywhere (except for inside the wholes where the loaches and antenna catfish are and didn't find any traces of them (even inside the filter on the rare chacne they got in through the outlet, nothing).  So if they are hiding they are VERY good.....or are hiding right inside a main disturbance area (where the loaches are racing through every now and then).

Comment: @Allerleirauh Water was ok last I checked (according to the test chart at least ok). 
Fishes are 2x antenna catfish, 2x loaches, 5x Corydoras paleatus, 5x black mollies, 4x red heads, 5x harlequin fish ? , 10x fire tetras, 4x Zebrafish. and  3x helena snails

(have to say fishname translations are....ouch, never sure I got the right translation tehre).

Comment: Is one of the fish famous for eating small snails? I know, that ours were and so they would have eaten shrimp also

Comment: @Allerleirauh only WAY smaller snails....or at leats tried as the tower snails inside were a bit too hard for them (that is why we got those snail eating snails).  the fire tetra inside are a bit smaller than the shrimps and I didnt see any of them ever getting attacked. Also whlie watching the shrimps intently the first hour I put them in. I saw them swimming about and being afraid of the fish when they came near but nothing at all form any type of fish that seemed to indicate attacks or hunting behaviour

Comment: Have you done any medications to the tank, ever? Or was the tank used when you got it? I've seen this more in reef systems but if copper was ever used in the past, it can make a tank basically uninhabitable for some inverts like shrimp, again I've seen it more often with coral, but a possibility. Also, I'm assuming this tank was well established and cycled, it wasn't just setup or anything?